# How to test JAVA Aplication that connect through NTLM to a PROXY Server?

Tags: java, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient

I am a JAVA develper and I use Linux. I have an issue using HttpClient to connec to a REST API. But I have to connect to a proxy to get internet connection. The problem is i need to authenticate through a PROXY using the NTLM Windows protocol. The problem is how can I test my client to connect through NTLM. I use a simple authentication using UsernamePasswordCredentials, but when people try in their network they recive this message:

"Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication"

My questions again is, How can i test the situation? How can emulate this situation?

Best Regards!